# what do the words "bargain mile image" and " quirkiest" and " shadiest" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Harwin has many strip malls with discount shops and wholesale warehouses.
>
> Allison Wollam said that the street has a **"bargain mile"**  image among Houstonians (Houston citizens).The Houston Press stated that Harwin was "Houston's **shadiest**  and **quirkiest**  shopping hot spot."

What do these superlatives refer to? could you paraphrase the meaning of them in simple English, please?
My last concern has to do with the expression **bargain mile** . what does it mean?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A "bargain mile" is most likely a street or a stretch of a street where you can buy goods at low prices.

Comment: Paraphrase them?  "Shadiest" = "most shady" (but **not** literally most strewn by trees offering shade), "quirkiest" = "most quirky".  Look those up.

Answer (score 2):

**"[insert word here] mile"** in a context like this refers to a stretch of road that may have some stand-out characteristic. Like a stretch of road with a high density of car dealerships may be referred to as a "motor mile". So a "bargain mile" is a stretch of road known for bargains -- shops that offer unusually good deals.

I went and looked up the source of the quote and from the full context I think what they're trying to suggest is that it's an area known for bargains of dubious authenticity or quality (**shady**), with an usually wide variety of items for sale (**quirky**).

For example, the article mentions a "$175 wedding dress". Since wedding dresses are more typically in the $800 - $3000 range, one that's going for $175 is "**shady**" -- it might be a fake brandname ripoff from some sweatshop in China, or maybe it was just stolen off of the back of a truck somewhere. (Shady could also mean that the area is dangerous and known for criminal activity but after reading the article I think it's clear they mean the *merchandise* is shady.)

Then the article mentions a 500 pound brass statue of Buddah. That's sufficiently unusual to qualify for "**quirky**".

Answer (score 0):

The noun 'mile' refers to a large area

> [mile:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mile?q=mile) a large area

If you go by dictionaries, [shadiest](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shady?q=shadiest) and [quirkiest](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quirky?q=quirkiest) mean somewhat unusual/strange. Maybe, the deals there are *not transparent*.

But then that's what is expected at 'bargain' stores/streets. You don't know t*he actual price* and you start bargaining.

[In this original post](http://www.houstonpress.com/best-of/2005/shopping-and-services/best-mall-alternative-6605395), you'd find that this place is great for bargaining but all you need is a trick to bargain to get the best goods.

Comment: -By saying strange and Unsuall , does it convey that they may deceive people? I mean shadiest and quickest are disapproval adjectives ?

Comment: Yes..but not for deceiving people particularly! I think it's just that they have shady **merchandise or goods.** The original article reads: *"When speaking of this type of **shady merchandise**..."*

Comment: "Shady" in this context usually means "of uncertain legality."