# could you define " strip" and "ground zero" and "dirt" in this text, please?

Tags: word-meaning

Harwin has many strip malls with discount shops and wholesale warehouses. Allison Wollam said that the street has a "bargain mile" image among Houstonians (Houston citizens). The Houston Press stated that Harwin was "Houston's shadiest and quirkiest shopping hot spot."

Jenalia Moreno of the Houston Chronicle said that Harwin was "a **strip**  known by local fashionistas as **ground zero** for affordable purses, clothing, shoes and jewelry." Moreno also said "If you want name-brand purses, designer sunglasses or other accessories at dirt cheap prices, Houstonians know to hit shops lining Harwin Drive. Consumers buy the goods thinking they're getting a sweet deal — or just give a wink and a nod knowing the products could be fake.

Comment: This also refers to the same article as http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69810/what-do-the-words-bargain-mile-image-and-quirkiest-and-shadiest-mean

Answer (score 4):

Strip would refer to a section of land or area, or possibly referring back to the [strip mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_mall) referenced earlier.  Usually it refers to a section of a road.  [The Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_Strip) in Las Vegas is a notable example.

[Ground zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_zero) is a euphemism for the origin of something.  Ground zero of a biological outbreak would be where the virus first started infecting people.  It started as meaning the point on the earth where a bomb was detonated.  In the USA Ground Zero (proper) would refer to the World Trade Center in NYC where terrorists struck on 9/11.

Dirt goes with dirt cheap, a saying indicating very cheap. Since dirt is everywhere its not expensive, so dirt cheap would be the same as very cheap.